# Xpage with Bootstrap panels: how to set active tab when xpage is opened?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs, xpages

I want to control which tab is active when an Xpages is opened (it will depend where in the workflow the document is).

Below I have two bootstrap tabs, neither of which is active or shown when the page is loaded. However, the output script should do that for me? It seems to do nothing. What is wrong?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:script src="/jQueryXSnippet.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:div styleClass="row">
        <xp:div styleClass="col-sm-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="list1">
                <li role="presentation" class="tab">
                    <a data-target="#inventory" data-toggle="tab">
                        Inventory
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a data-target="#beingBuilt" data-toggle="tab">
                        Being Built
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="inventory">
                    <xp:panel>
                        <xp:div styleClass="row"
                            style="height:20.00px">
                        </xp:div>
                        <div class="well well-sm">
                            <div class="form-group">DATA</div>
                        </div>
                    </xp:panel>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="beingBuilt">
                    <xp:panel>
                        <xp:div styleClass="row"
                            style="height:20.00px">
                        </xp:div>
                        <div class="well well-sm">
                            <div class="form-group">DATA</div>
                        </div>
                    </xp:panel>
                </div>
            </div>
        </xp:div>
    </xp:div>
    <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock2">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[$(document).ready(function()
{       
     x$("#{id:beingBuilt}").tab("show");    
}
)]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSJS code to

```
   <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock2">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[$(document).ready(function() {      
            $("[data-target='#beingBuilt'").tab("show");    
        })]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
```

Your div with id "beingBuilt" gets rendered to

[image]

That's why you have to search for an element with attribute `data-target="#beingBuilt"`. You can do this with pure jQuery this way:

```
$("[data-target='#beingBuilt'")
```